# Laravel 5.2 timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Okay so i'm trying to make some simple database schemas using Laravel 5.2 migrations.
They're pretty basic for now. The issue is that the result table created does not reflect in mysql what I dictated in the schema builder.
For example:[image]
creates the following table (ignore the picture after the table):
[image]

I'm pretty sure that If I wanted to allow nulls I should be using nullableTimestampts() also no default values and no "on update CURRENT TIMESTAMP" etc.

What am I missing here?
The aritsan commands were pretty straightforward:

```
php artisan make:migration create_table_institutes --create=institutes
php artisan migrate
```

I am on Ubuntu 14.04, php7, Apache mysql
Here is my seeding code:

```
DB::table('institutes')->insert([
    'name' => 'Ncbi',
    'base_curl' => 'eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/',
]);
```

Comment: You can use `->useCurrent()` for setting default values.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, I can also update it manually via sql. Is this though how it's supposed to be done? I'm ultimately trying to find why isn't the table created properly

Comment: Tbh, I don't think that should be the correct schema. What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the Schema Builder's `timestamps` method [creates nullable timestamp columns](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L785-L795) by design since Laravel 5.2. The `nullableTimestamps` method is just a synonym which is more explicit as to how the timestamps are created, and all it does is [call the `timestamps` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L782) internally.

So if you need timestamp fields that are not `nullable`, then you need to manually create them. Also for the `created_at` column to be populated automatically with the current timestamp by MySQL, it needs a default values. So this:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Should be replaced with this:

```
$table->dateTime('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->dateTime('updated_at')->nullable();
```

For versions older that MySQL 5.6.5 where `DATETIME` columns cannot have a default value, a `TIMESTAMP` column can be used instead:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

Although, if you're using Eloquent, aside from the `created_at` column which is always populated when a model entry is created, the other columns **should** be `nullable` as they will get values assigned only when updated or soft deleted.

Comment: Thanks! that was very useful. Half the question is answered now. When I seed my database though, I get null created_at columns when the whole purpose of timestamps is...to time stamp unless I explicitly update via sql.

Comment: Then please include the seeding code as well in your question.

Comment: I will, but does it matter? the point of the created timestamp is to update on create and of the modified to update on edit

Comment: I do not have the reputation yet to edit, but here it is: `DB::table('institutes')->insert([
            'name' => 'Ncbi',
            'base_curl' => 'eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/',
        ]);`

Comment: It does matter, because I would like to see how you are seeding the database. Are you using plain queries, model factories, etc? The `created_at` does not populate by magic when an entry is created in the table :).

Comment: You can't edit your own question? I'm not aware of any reputation restrictions for this.

Comment: Apologies, been working since morning. Yes I just edited my question

Comment: MySQL does not populate the `created_at` column with the current timestamp unless you specify that as the default value. I've updated my answer explaining how to implement that.

Comment: thanks, you might want to add updated_at at your second row :)

Comment: As a side note, if you were using an [Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) for your `institutes` table when seeding, then the `created_at` column would be populated by Eloquent, without the need for the default value at the database level.

Comment: I am planning on using the models in the future. I just need some sample data. By the way, the created_at column throws an exception: Invalid Default Value. I added this instead `$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));` just for the created_at so update your question with that maybe

Comment: The ability to set default values to a `DATETIME` column was added in MySQL 5.6.5, so I'm guessing you're running a version older than that, where it works only for `TIMESTAMP` columns. I've updated my answer to reflect that, but the recommendation is when possible to upgrade to the latest versions, because they offer bug fixes, security updates, sometimes performance enhancements and, as seen in this case, new features. I see you've already upgraded to the newly released PHP 7, so a MySQL upgrade might also be a good choice :).